How do I pass a field value in docx to a variable in LaTeX?
I'm looking into automating the typesetting of corporate memos drafted in Word-format (.docx) using pandoc. I have found the default LaTeX template, but I seem to be missing a basic understanding of how pandoc treats variables.
These memos have some bespoke structural elements such as the name of the client, the reference number in our systems, etc. which I would like to send to a specific spot in the LaTeX template. So, essentially, I would like to "tag" text in the .docx file and pass that text to a variable in the template.
I was under the impression that I could do that by doing this in the docx file:
$variable_name$TEXT$variable_name%
But that does not seem to work. Neither does applying a custom MS Word-style named after variable_name to that the text.
Does Pandoc have this functionality at all?

I'm not very familiar with pandoc, but AFAICS it does not actually extract even basic .docx metadata -, e.g. it will get the Title from the first line in the doc, not the built-in document properties. Nor do you seem to be able to put a "yaml metadata object" inside the .docx . So I think your main option would be to generate a suitable .yaml file from the properties/fields/content controls in the document, then provide that to pandoc...

If you can process the .docx client-side using the Word object model, you could probably use VBA to extract your metadata into a suitable text (.yaml) file. If you are working server-side, you'd have to find something that can already do that or perhaps write something using the open XML sdk or (say) a Python library.

No, word documents contain very little structured formatting and a lot of noise in the form of layouting info etc. I don't quite understand why you would want to use word if you're going to use LaTeX for typesetting anyway? Most people using pandoc and latex write their input document in markdown, with some yaml metadata.

The Word template is well-established along the end users. I’m not looking to pass document properties so much as field values in the document itself. I’ll have to look into VBA and Python libraries. Ideally it would happen server side: dropping the docx to generate a pdf with latex in the background.

I'm creating a .tex version using pandoc and then using the pylatexenc library to parse and modify the .tex file.  If I let the end users use a predefined Wordtemplate, their .docx file looks fine on itself but at the same time the pandoc output is predictable enough to parse with pylatexenc.
